# Can you switch the type of WordPress site you have?

Tags: plugins

My company had our WordPress website made through [Propertyware](http://www.propertyware.com/) or [Real Page](https://www.realpage.com/). The issue is, it's a different type of WordPress than others. (We did not realize there were different types.)

Our installation will not allow plugins to be used. Is there a way to switch your website to another type of WordPress?

Comment: What do you mean by "different type" of WordPress.

Comment: Check if you are accessing the site through the admin

Comment: The only different types of WordPress I can think of is `wordpress.com` vs `Self Hosted` or `Single Site` vs `Multi-site`. You probably don't have a different "type" of WordPress, you just probably are lacking admin permissions.

Comment: ....or they have a specific theme installed that is optimized for what the site does. But checking their user level (admin, etc) is a good first step, as stated above. Only admin-level users can add/delete plugins via the WP Admin interface.

Answer (score 2):

Generally self–hosted version of WordPress is not considered to have types. Other than *multisite* for hosting multiple sites on single WordPress installation.

From quick look you seem to have used hosted site from a company that built *on top* of WordPress.

To switch to a generic self–hosted WP installation you would need to:

1. Acquire standard WP export file of your content or re–create the content on the new site.
2. Come up with replacement functionality for whatever you were getting from the hosted platform.

Depending on exact platform moving away can range from trivial (wordpress com by Automattic will happily give you export file and often even exact theme you were using) to highly challenging (specialized platforms with complex proprietary functionality).

Answer (score 2):

There is one case where I've seen a super-customized WordPress website, where the end user could not install plugins or configure anything. It was basically a fork of WordPress - they started out with WordPress code, but they customized so much it wasn't actually WP anymore. You could not update Core, you could not install additional plugins, it was basically frozen in time. And since the developers didn't keep it synced up with WP Core, it was also very vulnerable to security issues.

As others have mentioned in the comments, it's also possible they set you up with a WordPress.com site, where you can only choose from a handful of plugins available to all sites, you can't add any custom plugins or many mainstream plugins.

If you can edit your question and upload a screenshot of your wp-admin area (redacted if needed) that may help determine whether it's a WordPress.com site or some odd fork of WP that you may need to rebuild from the ground up.